# Django Query using .order_by() and .latest()

Tags: python, django, sql-order-by

I have a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, editable=False)

   class Meta:
      get_latest_by = 'creation_date'
```

I had a query in my view that did the following:

```
instances = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('creation_date')
```

And then later I wanted `instances.latest()`, but it would not give me the correct instance, in fact it gave me the first instance. Only when I set order_by to `-creation_date` or actually removed the order_by from the query did `.latest()` give me the correct instance. This also happens when I test this manually using python manage.py shell instead of in the view.

So what I've done now is in the Model's Meta I've listed `order_by = ['creation_date']` and not used that in the query, and that works.

I would have expected `.latest()` to always return the most recent instance based on a (date)(time) field. Could anyone tell me whether it's correct that `.latest()` behaves strangely when you use `order_by` in the query?

Comment: Only when I set order_by to -creation_date or actually removed the order_by from the query did .latest() give me the correct instance... Could you explain that please what does it meant by this sentence?i didn't understand...

Answer (score 76, accepted):

> I would have expected .latest() to always return the most recent instance based on a (date)(time) field.

The [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest-field-name-none) says that

> If your model's `Meta` specifies `get_latest_by`, you can leave off the `field_name` argument to `latest()`. Django will use the field specified in `get_latest_by` by default.

All this means is that when you fire `MyModel.objects.latest()` you will get the latest instance based on the date/time field. And when I tested your code using sample data, it indeed did.

> And then later I wanted instances.latest(), but it would not give me the correct instance, in fact it gave me the first instance.

You have misunderstood the way `latest()` works. When called on *MyModel.objects* it returns 
the latest instance in the *table*. When called on a *queryset*, `latest` will return the first object in *the queryset*. Your queryset consisted of all instances of `MyModel` ordered by `creation_date` in ascending order. It is only natural then that `latest` on this queryset should return the *first* row *of the queryset*. This incidentally happens to be the oldest row in the *table*.

One way to get a better understanding is to view the query fired for `latest`.

Case 1:

```
from django.db import connection
MyModel.objects.latest()
print connection.queries[-1]['sql']
```

This prints:

```
SELECT "app_mymodel"."id", "app_mymodel"."creation_date" FROM 
"app_mymodel" ORDER BY "app_mymodel"."creation_date" DESC LIMIT 1
```

Note the ordering by `creation_date DESC` and the `LIMIT` clause. The former is thanks to `get_latest_by` whereas the latter is the contribution of `latest`.

Now, case 2:

```
MyModel.objects.order_by('creation_date').latest()
print connection.queries[-1]['sql']
```

prints

```
SELECT "app_mymodel"."id", "app_mymodel"."creation_date" FROM 
"app_mymodel" ORDER BY "app_mymodel"."creation_date" ASC LIMIT 1
```

Note that the ordering has changed to `creation_date ASC`. This is the result of the explicit `order_by`. The `LIMIT` is tacked on er, later courtesy `latest`.

Let us also see Case 3: where you explicitly specify the `field_name` for `objects.latest()`.

```
MyModel.objects.latest('id')
print connection.queries[-1]['sql']
```

shows

```
SELECT "app_mymodel"."id", "app_mymodel"."creation_date" FROM "app_mymodel"
ORDER BY "app_mymodel"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent explanation! You've made it very clear to me how .latest() works and what I've been doing wrong. Especially the SQL trick is helpful. That will definitely come in handy in the future.

Comment: What if I just want to have only 1 specific most recently inserted column value? Let's say :select "app_mymodel"."id" FROM 
"app_mymodel" ORDER BY "app_mymodel"."creation_date" ASC LIMIT 1, what is the equivalent python code?

Comment: Now you should update your answer because ```MyModel.objects.latest()``` and ```MyModel.objects.all().latest(')``` return the same results..

Answer (score 9):

I guess this is a known [bug in Django](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11283) that was fixed after 1.3 was released.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
latestsetuplist = SetupTemplate.objects.order_by('-creationTime')[:10][::1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**if we have the value of id or date**

```
post_id = BlogPost.objects.get(id=id)
try:
   previous_post = BlogPost.objects.all().order_by('id')[post_id.id-2:post_id.id-1]
except:   
   previous_post = None
try:
   next_post = BlogPost.objects.all().order_by('id')[post_id.id:post_id.id+1]
except:
  next_post = None
```

it worked for me, even if an id is missing it picks next or previous value to that