# Using django aggregates as filter clauses

Tags: django, django-models, python

Is there a better way to do this?

```
# Get an instance of the class I am interested in. It has a manytomany relation
instance = Class.objects.get(pk=1)

# Get the highest start date out of all the objects in the manytomany set
max_date = instance.related_set.aggregate(Max("start_date"))

# Return the object with the highest start date in the manytomany set
query_result = instance.related_set.filter(start_date=max_date['start_date__max'])
```

There must be a more elegant way to do this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would using the latest() method for getting the "max" date suit your needs?

[`django-query-using-order-by-and-latest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736964/django-query-using-order-by-and-latest)

might be of interest.

Comment: latest() is exactly what I was looking for.
thanks for the help!