# 'latest' django model is not latest?

Tags: python, django

Using Django 1.6:

Getting a model from the DB using `latest` returns a model but the `created` date on the instance returned lacks the microseconds, which means that it's actually not the latest, which has the same date stamp, but with the microseconds included and is therefore later (boolean comparison of `datetime.datetime` objects confirms it). What's going on?

```
myModel(models.model):
    <lots of fields>
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And is being retrieved with:
    latest = cls.objects.latest('created')

And:

```
latest.created
datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 11, 17, 8, 43)
```

Yet:

```
model_i_last_created.created
datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 11, 17, 8, 43, 849155)
```

**Update:** I create three models using `.create` The one returned by `latest` or `last` is the first one I created, not the last.

Comment: Does cls.objects.all().order_by('-created') honor the order?

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3737410/2255491

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Query using .order\_by() and .latest()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736964/django-query-using-order-by-and-latest)

Comment: I can't see why it is ignoring the microseconds though.

Comment: @DavidW. The issue is that that is for an older version of Django and I have tried with `.last` instead of `.latest` and still get the same results.