# How to use Meta attribute get_latest_by properly with pk in django?

Tags: django

I'm using q.latest() for retrieving most recent object from the queryset, setting `get_latest_by = 'created'` in it's model's `Meta` class.

For example:

```
class A(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'created'
```

But since django's `DateTimeField` supports only to seconds, with no micro second support, I think my system isn't properly retrieving latest object from the queryset.

Maybe this is because there are some records in the table with the same `created` value, though they are not created at exactly same time (within micro seconds).

So I'm trying to use `pk` for `get_latest_by` attribute in `Meta` class rather than `created`, but due to absence of my deep understanding of how the `latest()` and `get_latest_by` works together, I'm not sure it is correct way to just put `get_latest_by = 'pk'`.

Is it ok to just put `get_latest_by = 'pk'`? and what does `latest()` exactly do on the backside of django?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Query using .order\_by() and .latest()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736964/django-query-using-order-by-and-latest)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`latest` is basically just a shortcut for `order_by` followed by `get` to get the last item in the queryset ordered by `get_latest_by` field.

`pk` ordering is ok, but it relies on assumptions about how your app and the db backend work (eg you import data starting at high number pk 9999... will it ever 'fill in' the missing 1, 2, 3, 100, 2000 keys if you insert new data later?)

in future Django will support microseconds https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19716

for now the best thing would be to combine the two, i.e. `order_by('created', 'pk')`

unfortunately `get_latest_by` and `latest` don't let you specify a compound ordering (and it removes the default `pk` ordering) so you might prefer to manually do:

```
.order_by('-created', '-pk').get()
```

(note that `get` gets the *first* item in the queryset so you need to invert the order with a `-` prefix to fetch the *latest*)

Answer (score 1):

As of version 2.0, Django has added support for multiple columns in the [get_latest_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#get-latest-by) field. Use list syntax, e.g.

```py
get_latest_by = ['created_at', 'pk']
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).