# Django SQL: related tables, use latest() on field of parent table

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Using .latest() on related tables, does the double-underscore syntax for related tables work?

```
class OrderHeader(models.model):
    order_id = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=100)
    last_modified = models.DateField()

class OrderLine(models.model):
    line_nbr = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(OrderHeader,on_delete=models.Cascade)

class RefundLine(models.model):
    line_nbr = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(OrderHeader,on_delete=models.Cascade)
    refund_type = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

How do I find the `last_modified` of RefundLine where `refund_type = 1`?

I can not make head or tail of the django documentation. My guess

```
RefundLine.objects.filter(refund_type=1).latest(order__last_modified)
```

results in an error `order__last_modified` is not defined

PS What is `latest()`? A synonym for `Max()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Query using .order\_by() and .latest()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736964/django-query-using-order-by-and-latest)

Comment: although latest() returns a record and aggregate a dict, is the value always the same with ....latest("a_datetime_field") and ...aggregate(Max("a_datetime_field")) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
RefundLine.objects.filter(refund_type=1).latest('order__last_modified')
```

You have forgotten single quotes .

latest() gives you the last modified value.
or you can try order_by('-id') it also gives you the last value.

Comment: `order_by('-id')` will not give last modified it will return object which created recently *(not modified)* to get modified using dates is better option.

Comment: yeah, last_modified is in this case copied from another cache so the activity in this table is not necessarily related to the last_modified field.